# Internet explorer auto height with position absolute

Tags: explorer

I'm trying to make my columns same height, it works for columns without problems, but I have div inside and it has position: absolute, in every browsers it works, but in explorer there is a problem, can you help me?

http://days.cz.uvds268.active24.cz/new/

SCREEN: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqld6xrwb3wc2m4/Bez%20n%C3%A1zvu-1.jpg?dl=0

```
enter code here*
```

```css
row-full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.col-full-height {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* fix overflow */
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.col-xs-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none !important;
  }
}

/* vertical alignment styles */

.col-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.col-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* CSS of box */
#third .row-same-height >div:first-of-type .box{ position: absolute;}`
```

```html
<div class="row">
                        <div class="row-same-height ">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-height col-top">
                                <div class="box">
                                    <h2>DAYS MENU s.r.o.</h2> 
                                    <p>Naše společnost zahájila výrobu v lednu 1998. Díky vysoké kvalitě a příznivé ceně svých výrobků si brzy vybudovala pevnou pozici mezi konkurencí.</p>
                                    <p>Důkazem toho je i neustále se zvyšující počet spokojených zákazníků a pravidelných odběratelů. Snažíme se jim maximálně vyjít vstříc a podle jejich přání a požadavků pravidelně rozšiřujeme a obměňujeme naši nabídku hotových i mražených jídel.</p><br>
                                    <div class="row display-flex">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 vertical-align">
                                        <strong class="certifikace">Jsme držitelem certifikátů</strong><br><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <a href="pdf/certificate_haccp.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="image/certificate_haccp.png" alt="HACCP certifikát systému kvality" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <a href="pdf/certificate_bisnode.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="image/certificate_bisnode.png" alt="AA certifikát vysoké důvěryhodnosti" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-height ">
                                <div class="box">
                                    <h3>AKTUALITY</h3>
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <strong>4.3.2015 | HOTOVÁ TEPLÁ JÍDLA</strong>
                                        <p>Vážení zákazníci. Z důvodu plné kapacity vozidel pro rozvoz hotových teplých jídel již bohužel nepřijímáme nové drobné odběratele (obědy pro jednotlivce). Děkujeme za pochopení.</p>
                                    </blockquote>
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <strong>4.3.2015 | HOTOVÁ TEPLÁ JÍDLA</strong>
                                        <p>Vážení zákazníci, informace o složení našich jídel a alergenech v nich obsažených dle nařízení EU č.1169/2011 - O označování potravin - Vám na vyžádání zodpovíme na tel. č. 466 951 571 nebo jsou tyto informace k dispozici na našich stránkách v nabídce jídelníčků a v nabídce mražených jídel.</p>
                                    </blockquote>
                                    <a class="more-news" href="vsechny-aktuality.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>VŠECHNY AKTUALITY</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Which div ? Which IE version ? AND where the HTML/CSS code you tried ? Nobody can help without those informations.

Comment: There is div with class="row-same-height" on line 204 in source. Version of IE is 11.